# How to add an index to a referenced database table in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014

We have a need for a Reporting Database Solution that references our OLTP database solution. The only point of it is to hold indices that are only used by Reports, which in production will be a subscriber database in a transactional replication topology. I've created the solution in Visual Studio and added a database reference to the OLTP project.

However, when I try to reference the table to create the index on, like:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCIX_MyIndex] 
    ON [$(OltpDB)].dbo.[MyTable]
```

I get an error

> When you create an object of this type in a database project, the object's name must contain no more than two parts

WTF is this? How do I create the index? Is there a better way to handle report-only indices?

FWIW - Visual Studio 2015/SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0):

I was able to circumvent this error by changing the build action of the script to "Post Deploy." Not sure if this is the recommended approach, but it works.